# Microsoft.Bcl.Async trying to load System.Threading.Tasks 1.5.11.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, async-await

I've added Microsoft.Bcl.Build/Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async to some projects in my solution where I want to use async/await.
Everything works fine on my machine with .Net4.5 installed. However, when I start the application on a machine with only .Net4 installed, at some point, the application crashes with the following Exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Looking at the StackTrace, the exception seems to be generated in a third party library that we reference.

When I analyze the Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll provided by Microsoft.Bcl.Async, I see that it does reference System.Threading.Tasks Version 1.5.11.0, but version 2.6.10.0 is included in Microsoft.Bcl.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. You should upgrade and get rid of BCL Async. 4.5.2 also adds support for TLS 1.2 which is required by more services every day, eg Google, banks, airlines.

Comment: PS the machine that has "only" 4.0 may get 4.5.2 soon through Windows Update, if it hasn't already.

Comment: PPS - open source libraries have started dropping support for 4.0 in the 9 months. For example Json.NET 10.0 just dropped 4.0 support

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not using Microsoft.Bcl for fun you know? Not everyone can upgrade to 4.5 because of missing Windows XP support. And don't tell me that Windows XP is not supported as well. I know that. The machine has only 4.0 installed, because I uninstalled 4.5 to reproduce bug reports. Many customers have updates disabled for whatever reason.

Comment: I'll have to say it though. The killer is TLS 1.2. You won't be able to connect to web and REST services soon. As for reasons, as long as you include indemnity clauses in your contract that absolve you of security breaches caused by missing updates or broken encryption ...

Comment: Example - GMail requires TLS 1.2. You can's use SmtpClient to send email through Gmail if you use .NET 4.0. GDS services like Sabre require TLS 1.2. Sabre dropped support for anything less last December

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you have the wrong picture of the world of antiquated enterprise software. As I said, I can not possibly updgrade and lose Windows XP support, this just isn't a possibility. We also don't use GMail or whatever. Actually, in this world, you can be happy if the webservices you use actually use any kind of encryption. And even if we would need to use a webservice requiring TLS 1.2, we can always wrap it in our own, which would need to do anyway with services like GMail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Heck, do you know how many calls we got when we had to drop support for Pentium III (!!!) due to a third party library? Believe me, If I could, I would upgrade in an instant, but I am not the one who gets to decide that in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! It was actually very simple. I just had to copy and paste the binding redirects that nuget adds in the app.config files into the *.exe.config file. Then it just magically works. Easy fix.

Comment: Actually, you should upgrade to .NET 4.5 and get rid of BCL Async. .NET 4.0 is no longer supported. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when you create an installer, you need it to support the .net versions installed on the customer's machines. So your remark is off topic.

Comment: @Softlion on the contrary, it's the *applications* that install the runtime. As for "the .net versions installed" that's 4.5.2 at least, since the supported *Windows* versions come with it preinstalled. **NO OS Version** came with 4.0. Windows 7 had 3.5, Windows 8 had 4.5. Furthermore, 4.x versions are in-place upgrades so the application probably won't be running on 4.0 even in older OSs. And finally, 4.0 doesn't support TLS1.2 which is required for HTTPS communications nowadays. Unless they run on top of a 4.5+ runtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your evangelism was off-topic as soon as I wrote that Windows XP support is required.

Comment: How would you do this for a dll assembly/class library